# Выборка данных из трех таблиц

Tags: sql

Есть три таблицы:

1. results с полями patientID, doctorID, Title, Date
2. doctors с полями id, name
3. patients с полями id, fio

Мне нужно в итоге получить выборку с полями

patientID, Title, doctorID, Date, doctors.name, patients.fio

через left outer join смогла только из двух таблиц выполнить запрос.

Comment: *через left outer join смогла только* A нафига **внешнее** соединение? али может быть результат без доктора или без пациента?

Comment: Возможны записи в которых поля doctorID и/или patientID отсутствуют. А как нужно было?

Comment: *А как нужно было?* Ну... для меня, скажем, анализ, когда образец возник сам собой из ниоткуда, несколько странен... как и результат, который не врач получил, а типа ветром надуло...

Comment: Структуру БД не я делала, а я только работаю с тем что есть. Для меня тоже странно что в некоторых записях отсутствует врач и пациент.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примерно таким образом можно

```
SELECT p.id, r.Title, d.id, r.Date, d.name, p.fio
FROM doctors as d
INNER JOIN results as r
    ON d.id = r.doctorID
INNER JOIN patients as p
    ON p.id = r.patientID
```

Comment: Я так пробовала, но у меня почему-то в поле p.fio оказалось пусто для всех записей.

Comment: @НатальяСергеевна проверьте все связи...выберите сначала `SELECT *`, все должно быть ок

Comment: Да, разобралась. Спасибо

Comment: @VladChyorny обратите внимание на комментарий автора к вопросу и замените у себя в ответе INNER на LEFT.

Comment: Собственно оказывается, я и сама это сделала, но из-за того что поле p.fio пустое решила задать вопрос. Оказывается в данном случае в таблице results поле patientID везде пусто)

Comment: @Akina не вижу в этом проблемы...кому нужно тот заменит в зависимости от необходимости

Comment: @НатальяСергеевна Это следствие "кривой" структуры. В ней дополнительно должны быть внешние ключи, которые просто не позволят создать запись об анализе без заполнения полей врача и пациента существующими в данных ссылками.

Comment: Да, согласна.. структуру БД создавала не я. Я только работаю с тем, что есть. Подскажите пожалуйста, а как добавить условие отбора по датам? Например мне нужно получить все записи из results только за период с 01.08.2018 по 23.08.2018

Comment: @Igor у вас у всех врачей и пациентов id - 1....в таком случае конечно не правильно...но результат все равно правильный

Comment: copy paste и не отредактировал :-)
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2d3065158d28c669c5b71fa3ffcaee7d